# Text clipped by padding in big outlined TextInputLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

One of my apps contains some kind of "notes field", which is a big textinputlayout containing a potentially big text. I'm using this piece of layout (i removed some less relevant attributes):

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/notes_maximum_height"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/notes_minimum_height"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"
            android:paddingVertical="8dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I would like a vertical padding, so that the cursor and the first line don't "touch" the outline, and that's ok. The problem is, when the content reaches its maximum height and starts scrolling, i can see the text clipped by the padding and not touching the upper and lower part of the outline. So i tried with clipChildren set to false as i often do, but i had no luck. Same behavior. After a lot of failed attempts, i'm really wondering if this is even possible!

[image: The problem mentioned]

Comment: can you give `android:layout_marginVertical` a try instead of the vertical padding

Comment: Thanks but i already tried, the margin isn't even applied for the TextInputEditText, and even if it was, the clipping problem would still remain!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a real answer to this question. It seems i'm the only one with this problem, for some reason. The workaround i used is a combination of a smaller padding and a fade out effect on the edittext. So i simply added the following to the edittext:

```
android:paddingVertical="4dp"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

This is not what i wanted, but i tried solving this apparently simple problem for months and it's time to move on :D